# Java - a while loop (in Therad) causes high CPU just on Mac

Tags: java, multithreading, macos, while-loop

I need help,

I have this code, from a tutorial of Java game development,
When i run the code, the while loop (the thread)is giving my Macbook high CPU.

I have run this code on Ubuntu vm and on Windows 7 - on both, the CPU was low and normal,
if it's matter - the threads was around 27 - (In task manager / in activity monitor / in System monitor).

Mac - CPU is going high just on my mac now 89.7, sometimes more then 100:

[image: Mac CPU Image]

Ubuntu - CPU is low around 2:

[image]

PLEASE,

I know i can fix this with sleep:

```
thread.sleep(5);
```

But why it's working fine on other OS? Windows.. Linux..
I have test this code on other Macbook Air too. on the other mac it was high to.

Some info about my problem:

- I'm running mac OSX 10.11.5
- Java version:

  ```
  java version "1.8.0_91"
  Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_91-b14)
  Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.91-b14, mixed mode)
  ```
- Code:

Renderer Class:

```
package org.graphics;

import org.game.Game;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.awt.image.VolatileImage;

public class Renderer {

    private static Frame frame;
    private static Canvas canvas;

    private static int canvasWidth = 0;
    private static int canvasHeight = 0;

    private static final int GAME_WIDTH = 400;
    private static final int GAME_HEIGHT = 250;

    private static int gameWidth = 0;
    private static int gameHeight = 0;


    private static void getBestSize() {
        Toolkit toolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
        Dimension screenSize = toolkit.getScreenSize();

        boolean done = false;

        while (!done) {
            canvasWidth += GAME_WIDTH;
            canvasHeight += GAME_HEIGHT;

            if (canvasWidth > screenSize.width || canvasHeight > screenSize.height) {
                canvasWidth -= GAME_WIDTH;
                canvasHeight -= GAME_HEIGHT;

                done = true;
            }

        }

        int XDiff = screenSize.width - canvasWidth;
        int YDiff = screenSize.height - canvasHeight;
        int factor = canvasWidth / GAME_WIDTH;

        gameWidth = canvasWidth / factor + XDiff / factor;
        gameHeight = canvasHeight / factor + YDiff / factor;

        canvasWidth = gameWidth * factor;
        canvasHeight = gameHeight * factor;

    }

    private static void makeFullScreen() {
        GraphicsEnvironment env = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
        GraphicsDevice gd = env.getDefaultScreenDevice();

        if (gd.isFullScreenSupported()) {
            frame.setUndecorated(true);
            gd.setFullScreenWindow(frame);
        }
    }

    public static void init() {
        getBestSize();

        frame = new Frame();
        canvas = new Canvas();

        canvas.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(canvasWidth, canvasHeight));

        frame.add(canvas);

        makeFullScreen();

        frame.pack();
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);


        frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {

            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                Game.quit();
            }


        });

        frame.setVisible(true);

        startRendering();

    }

    private static void startRendering() {
        Thread thread = new Thread() {
            public void run() {

                GraphicsConfiguration gc = canvas.getGraphicsConfiguration();
                VolatileImage vImage = gc.createCompatibleVolatileImage(gameWidth, gameHeight);

                while (true) {
                    if (vImage.validate(gc) == VolatileImage.IMAGE_INCOMPATIBLE) {
                        vImage = gc.createCompatibleVolatileImage(gameWidth, gameHeight);
                    }

                    Graphics g = vImage.getGraphics();

                    //Start//

                    g.setColor(Color.black);
                    g.fillRect(0, 0, gameWidth, gameHeight);

                    //end//

                    g.dispose();

                    g = canvas.getGraphics();
                    g.drawImage(vImage, 0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight, null);

                    g.dispose();


                }
            }
        };
        thread.setName("Render Thread");
        thread.start();
    }
}
```

Game Class:

```
package org.game;

import org.graphics.Renderer;

public class Game {

    public static void main(String args[]){
        Renderer.init();
    }

    public static void quit(){
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: In Windows also. If you use while true without sleep, also high cpu.

Comment: where is the rest of Game class ?

Comment: side note : Most Renderer's static members should be non-static in my opinion

Comment: @niceman sorry, i just add the rest.

Comment: @x... Please check this again, run this code. or any other loop like this - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TNVHWROwYuM

Comment: I have the same issue on my linux machine, 100% usage of one of my cpu's cores

Comment: on The Windows machine and Ubuntu machine did you check the cores usage ? it did report around 6% but when I viewed cores usage I saw 100% in one of my cores almost all the time

Comment: @niceman - Check out this screen shot: http://i.imgur.com/j0XHiQP.png  And bdw, i use VM and running ubuntu, but i did try it on real windows machine. - and about your lest comment, my macbook air go really super hot when i run it on host, really hot! and on the VM - there is nothing at all. Do  i really need to check that?

Comment: this image shows that CPU usage is 1% http://imgur.com/gJAsZeb but when I select "System Load" tab, I get this : http://imgur.com/cVey8Xl

Comment: @niceman Thank you for the investigation, now i can sleep(5) good tonight...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm the guy who created that tutorial. I think I see what the problem is. When you asked me before what my CPU was, I was checking the CPU counter at the bottom of the activity monitor window, rather than the one for that specific process. My misunderstanding.

The reason why it's high is because we haven't yet implement any kind of sleeping yet. I plan to do that later on in an episode about frames-per-second control. Until then, it's normal for your CPU percentage to be high. Keep in mind that your total percentage of CPU available depends on the number of cores in your computer. In your case, the program is using 89.7% of ONE of your CPU cores.

Thanks very much for asking this question.

EDIT: Also, the reason why it's so high is because, since we don't tell it to sleep, it will execute the loop as fast as it possibly can, resulting the total (or nearly total) use of one of the CPU cores.

Comment: Thanks so much Samuel. the reason that i got so confused, is because every video that i saw didn't say that you should add to sleep.. and i don't know if they notice (I use a laptop) that the computer got real hot and fan goes crazy..